# How to edit my app full description on Google play store?

Tags: android, google-play

So I published my app on Google Play and it was pending so Google checks my app. But then they rejected my app and emailed me the reason:

> The app's full description mentions other brands: Telegram.
>
> The app's short description mentions other brands: Telegram.

Ironic is I cannot find a way to edit the app full/short descriptions on developer console.

It seems the only way is to change the package name and add my app as a new application.
Is that right? Or if there is a way to edit my app full/short descriptions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this not a programming question. Sadly this site is not an alternative to customer service. See [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746).

Comment: But I have seen many other similar questions without down vote or even with positive feedback. Also I know many platforms like Instagram, Onesignal and so forth direct users to here to ask their questions about any type of problem!

Comment: StackOverflow has a specific scope not just any type of problem. For Google Play concern you can still find alternative forum like Quora or Reddit. But if your question is about Google Play SDK or API then it should be on-topic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Within Play Developer Console click on the app, then choose Store Presence then Store Listing on the left side menu and you'll be able to edit your short and long descriptions.

Comment: It solved my issue. Thank you so much ;)